# timefold: is it possible to create random initial solution with construction heuristic?

Tags: java, random, optaplanner, timefold

I'm trying to use parallel restarts in my timefold model.

I want different initial solutions for each restart.
But I can't understand how to create random initial solution with construction heuristic phase.

Of course, I can create initial solution by myself, but I'm still wondering is it possible to use construction heuristic for that or not?

I've tried this configuration:

```
  <constructionHeuristic>
    <changeMoveSelector>
      <entitySelector>
        <selectionOrder>RANDOM</selectionOrder>
      </entitySelector>
    </changeMoveSelector>
  </constructionHeuristic>
```

And I've got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The <constructionHeuristic> contains a changeMoveSelector (ChangeMoveSelectorConfig(EntitySelectorConfig(null), null)) that contains an entitySelector (EntitySelectorConfig(null)) without explicitly configuring the <queuedEntityPlacer>.
```

My timefold version 1.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but we could add a specific phase for it (or reuse the ConstructionHeuristic phase for it), like

```
<randomConstruction/>
```

Meanwhile, you can define a CustomPhase