# Timefold: score calculation in the custom phase

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

I'm trying to create [random initial solution with the custom phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77859845/timefold-is-it-possible-to-create-random-initial-solution-with-construction-heu). And I'm wondering, is it possible to access score calculation in this phase?

I mean, I'd like to check scores of some moves and then choose the best, but with some randomness.

I've checked, that `scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution().getScore())` doesn't change during the phase.

`constraintVerifier` looks good, but it doesn't provide actual score of the constraint.

Of course, there is an option to create score calculation "by hand".

Is there an easier way?